# Angular library : use exported scss files from one module into other library modules

Tags: angular, sass, angular-library

### EDIT :

I realized that my angular project folder (what I called "library") was not composed of several modules like `utils` or `breadcrumb` but that they were in fact libraries... So instead of import modules in my parent app, I imported libraries... Due to this point, it was normal I can't share things between my libraries like I asked to.

I've recreated ONE library with expected modules and now everything works like a charm : I succeed to share styles across all my library (by specifiing the path of my scss files), and from my library to parent app like explained below.

---

I am building an Angular library with couple of modules, all generated with command `ng generate library <module-name>`. One of these modules is `utils` and contains some methods, service and scss files. I was able to export the scss file thanks to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66494915/how-to-add-scss-of-angular-library-to-bundle-using-ng-packagr) (see Orson's answer). In my case, scss files are located in module's root (on the same level as `package.json`).

`ng-package.json` of `utils` :

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/utils",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  },
  "assets": ["styles.scss", "variables.scss", "components.scss"]
}
```

`package.json` of `utils` :

```
{
  "name": "utils",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "exports": {
    "./ics-styles": {
      "sass": "./styles.scss"
    }
  }
}
```

When I build utils, I see `styles.scss`, `variables.scss` and `components.scss` files into `dist` folder.

In parallel, I have an Angular application (let's call it "parent app") which use many modules from the library :

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.5
Node: 18.12.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.8.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.3.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router     

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------  
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.5
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.5
@angular/cdk                    13.3.7
@angular/cli                    13.3.5
@schematics/angular             13.3.5
ng-packagr                      13.3.1
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.4
```

Parent app has a `SharedModule` which import `UtilsModule`. I am able to import and use scss from `utils` thanks to this import in scss files : `@import 'utils/ics-styles';`. It works perfectly, all variables and mixins from `UtilsModule` are available.

Now, I want to use exported scss files from `UtilsModule` into another module of the library, let's say `BreadcrumbModule`. I proceeded in the same way, importing `UtilsModule` in `breadcrumb.module.ts` :

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { UtilsModule } from 'utils';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './breadcrumb.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [BreadcrumbComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, TranslateModule, UtilsModule],
  exports: [BreadcrumbComponent],
})
export class BreadcrumbModule {}
```

Then, in `breadcrumb.component.scss`, I use `@import 'utils/ics-styles';` but it gives me the following error on serve or build :

```
./projects/breadcrumb/src/lib/breadcrumb.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import 'utils/ics-styles';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  projects\breadcrumb\src\lib\breadcrumb.component.scss 1:9  root stylesheet



× Failed to compile.
```

I tried to change scss import with `@import '~utils/ics-styles';` or `@import '~@utils/ics-styles';` but got the same error message.

Any idea to make scss file from `utils` useable into other library modules would be appreciated. Thanks !